# Javascript to return numbers in href link click

Tags: javascript

How would i return the value '170236' when clicking 'Enquire' in this example?

```
<a class="mylink" 
href="https://www.mydomain.co.uk/help/contact/170236">Enquire</a>
```

I need it for a variable in Google Tag Manager

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getLastSegment()
{
  var links = document.getElementsByClassName('mylink');
  var link = links[0].href;
  alert(link.substr(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
}
```

```html
<a class="mylink" 
href="https://www.mydomain.co.uk/help/contact/170236" onClick="getLastSegment()">Enquire</a>
```

Comment: I forgot to say its for Google Tag Manger, so i need the javascript for a variable in GTM

Comment: @chappers okay, so can't you just use a return statement and return the segment you need instead of using alert()?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
function() {

var links = document.getElementsByClassName('mylink test tester');
var link = links[0].href;
var element = link.substr(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

return element;

}
```